# Call Trace on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel

I see a call trace in the syslog. 
Anybody an idea what is at fault here?

```
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931568] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931619] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 909 at /build/linux-kOWph6/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3675 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931623] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931625] Modules linked in: uas usb_storage btrfs xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c rfcomm snd_hda_codec_hdmi bnep arc4 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dw_dmac_core snd_hda_intel 8250_dw snd_hda_codec intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel nls_iso8859_1 iwlmvm snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep mac80211 irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_pcm iwlwifi cfg80211 snd_seq_midi aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aes_x86_64 snd_seq lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq_device snd_timer joydev snd ir_lirc_codec input_leds lirc_dev ir_xmp_decoder ir_mce_kbd_decoder idma64 soundcore virt_dma ir_sharp_decoder ir_sanyo_decoder mei_me shpchp intel_lpss_pci mei ir_jvc_decoder ir_sony_decoder ir_rc6_decoder hci_uart btusb btrtl ir_rc5_decoder btqca btbcm ir_nec_decoder btintel bluetooth rc_rc6_mce ite_cir rc_core intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss acpi_als acpi_pad mac_hid kfifo_buf industrialio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid mmc_block i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper e1000e syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ptp fb_sys_fops pps_core sdhci_pci sdhci drm nvme ahci libahci video i2c_hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint hid pinctrl_intel fjes
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931760] CPU: 0 PID: 909 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931764] Hardware name:                  /NUC6i5SYB, BIOS SYSKLi35.86A.0052.2016.0910.1456 09/10/2016
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931767]  0000000000000286 0000000003f4bfbe ffff88025fe6b920 ffffffff813f1fe3
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931773]  ffff88025fe6b968 ffffffffc02c09a0 ffff88025fe6b958 ffffffff81081212
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931778]  ffff88025fb85000 ffff88025effa148 ffff88025fb86000 ffff880264fceb78
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931783] Call Trace:
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931794]  [] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931802]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931806]  [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931845]  [] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931879]  [] skl_update_wm+0x185/0x610 [i915_bpo]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931933]  [] ? intel_ddi_enable_transcoder_func+0x17f/0x260 [i915_bpo]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.931968]  [] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932019]  [] haswell_crtc_enable+0x761/0x8e0 [i915_bpo]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932068]  [] intel_atomic_commit+0x5d6/0x14a0 [i915_bpo]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932108]  [] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932138]  [] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932156]  [] drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x76/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932184]  [] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x62/0x100 [drm]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932213]  [] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3cc/0x4f0 [drm]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932234]  [] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932241]  [] ? __set_current_blocked+0x36/0x60
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932266]  [] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932272]  [] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932278]  [] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932283]  [] ? __set_current_blocked+0x36/0x60
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932287]  [] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932292]  [] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x8e/0xc0
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932299]  [] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Nov 22 15:03:00 NUC kernel: [205544.932303] ---[ end trace 378868ad0954bfdc ]---
```

Comment: Some parts of the trace hint at GPU/Xorg: "Comm: Xorg", "drm"

Answer (score 0):

This kernel stack trace is inside the `drm` module which is part of the graphics driver stack of (integrated) Intel graphics chipsets.